# Tomcat 404 error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to my deployed EE app with the given extension of '/jee' however I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access this. I have this line added to my server.xml:

```
 <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

    <Context docBase="C:\Users\user\workspace\EE\j2eeapplication\target\j2eeapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" path="/jee" reloadable="true" />

  </Host>
```

I am trying to get it to redirect to my main-flow which has a view 'welcome'

```
    <view-state id="welcome">
</view-state>
```

and my welcome.xhtml is in the same folder as my main-flow.xml. I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning but my welcome file as specified in the web.xml:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and here is my index.jsp:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=app/main" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to EE and I'm stumped as to why I'm getting the 404 error, is there anything I can try?

Comment: What URL did you use to access the page?

Comment: I'm using localhost:8081/jee  (8081 is the port im using)

Comment: From the information above, I would guess either your `docBase` in `server.xml` is not pointing to a right location, or there is a wrong configuration in your servlet context. My suggestion here would be opening a new default EE project which is accessible to the index.jsp, and then modify from it. Then you will know what is wrong with your current setting. This will save time for you to find out what is wrong here as in my opinion, there are many possible reasons.

Comment: the docBase is pointing to the unpacked war folder, is this correct use?

Comment: you can also try getting the browser to load static files in your app. e.g.. localhost:8081/jee/images/something.jpg - this will show if the docpath is correct. if it is, it then a problem with the JSP registration.